# On a network of computers one has a different external IP. How can I find out what's causing that?

Tags: networking

It's a Windows 8 laptop, plugged (ethernet) into a switch next to a few other computers. I've noticed that google goes to .de (based in uk), checked language, location settings, found nothing, checked external IP, found that it differs from the computers in the office. Can't see a proxy or an active vpn (there's a "test" vpn that's off). `tracert` shows the same route as the other computers, `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com` gives the same, correct external ip address. going to whatismyip or similar however gives a wildly different ip. It also seems to change regularly, every few hours, cycles around a few IPs (i'll have to double check that).

Comment: Are the DNS settings the same as the other machines? Has the `hosts` file been modified?

Comment: DNS: an in-house DNS, then the two google DNSs, assigned by DHCP (as on other computers). hosts empty (comments only)

Comment: sounds like you may want to stop using that system, nuke it from orbit, and start fresh.

Comment: Can you post the pc's routing table?

Comment: i would rather not. but suffice to say, it doesn't seem to differ from other computers' routing.

Comment: btw the nuking did give me an idea, running linux from an usb and see what happens, thanks for that. i just dont have my trusty pendrive with me.

Comment: Don't worry, posting the routing table is not a security risk if your network security is half-decent.

Comment: well, one of the computers' http data is tunneled somewhere and nobody knows why, so i have to wonder about how secure it is. Could you tell me what to look for? the only difference i can see between other computers' table and this one's is the computer's (internal) ip